# What is the proper way to eager load associated objects for a 'has_many' association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, eager-loading

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to eager load associated objects for a `has_many` association. That is, I have the following models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Since I frequently retrieve `comments` when I load `articles` I would like to eager load `comments` each time I search for `articles`, for example in these cases:

```
# In these cases the eager loading should happen.
Article.find(1)
Article.where(:title => 'Sample text')
@current_user.articles
```

What is the proper way to handle this issue? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method, like in following:

```
Article.includes(:comments).where(title: 'Sample text')
```

For your first case, you don't really need eager loading, since you only select one record, so this is not n+1 problem. You can just do:

```
article = Article.find(1)
article.comments
```

If you use include your articles frequently, you may define scope:

```
scope :with_comments, -> { includes(:comments }
```

and simply call it:

```
Article.with_comments.where(title: 'Sample text')
```

When your relation into which you want to include `comments` comes from another association, nothing changes, you can do both:

```
@current_user.articles.includes(:comments)
```

and

```
@current_user.articles.with_comments
```

Comment: Should I add the `includes` statement directly to the `has_many` association?

Comment: @user502052 no, since it even won't do your job.

Comment: And how to solve the eager loading in cases when I run code as like: `@current_user.articles`? - Note: I updated the question since I forgot to add the mentioned case.

Comment: @user502052 I edited my answer to cover your expanded question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `comments` to be eager loaded automatically whenever you load article, you can use `default_scope` on Article model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  default_scope :include => :comments
end
```